# Can anyone out there help me for ocr business card scanner in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, ocr

I am new in android field. I want to make business card scanner related with ocr in android.

For that I use this site refrence .

- http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

now based on this site I complete all the task . but then I could not decide what to do . .I don't have a perfect direction for get output in OCR Code.

I have related 3 choice  :

1. http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Camera/wordsnap-ocr/net/bitquill/ocr/OCRThread.java.htm   (JAVA OCR code )
2. http://code.google.com/p/wordsnap-ocr/source/browse/#svn/trunk   (word-snap code for ocr)
3. http://www.itwizard.ro/mezzofanti-installrun-tutorial-243.html  (mezzofanti)

plz , give some solution  in a right direction. . Thanx. .

Comment: Hi - you'll need to ask more specific questions. Are you asking for a recommendation between the three libraries? You might have to name them rather than just posting links. And really we don't know your situation well enough to suggest one anyway - why not just try one, see how far you get then post back with whatever problems you encounter? Unfortunately they'd need to be specific questions, rather than just "quality of OCR results" or similar.

Comment: hi Rup. .Thanx for your help. . Actually I install ndk also I have cygwin is there . .I used eclipse for android. now the actual situation is  : I could not find out the OCR related code. .for android. .even I dnt know the code in three links . whick I give above ,  takes me in a right direction or not. .plz suggest me. .

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning commercial usage of your software, you may want to look at our [ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/). It has a business card reader functionality already built-in and it supports Android It’s not affordable for free-to-use programs, but when it comes to business software – ABBYY OCR technologies can add a serious value to your product, so consider trying it out.