# Is there an OCR open source library or sdk (free) for Android & iOS?

Tags: android, ios, open-source, sdk, ocr

I am looking for an OCR open source library or sdk (free) for Android and iOS app..

I will be scanning business cards to pull content. The content pulled will be stored as contacts in the cloud, on the phone, and choice of email account.

Any resources out there for this would be very appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282046/can-anyone-out-there-help-me-for-ocr-business-card-scanner-in-android/7398074

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062755/ocroptical-character-recoginition-libraries-for-iphone/9064231#9064231

Comment: possible duplicate of [android OCR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).

Comment: But thats not good to work, Having lot of issues and its not reliable

Comment: svn chekout not working

Comment: I used tesseract ocr library. But it's not giving accurate result and implementation is also complex.

Comment: hi i have also used tesseract ocr library. and not getting the clear text when i clicked image from camara  and processed . please suggest other library for ios app

Comment: So far Tesseract is the best free solution of mobile OCR. I wouldn't expect we could see any better and free alternatives anytime soon.

Comment: Although integration is quite simple, the overall performance is slow and inaccurate even with whitelist turned on. PS: I'm testing paid frameworks and BlinkOCR seems to be pretty good.